# Netbeans can't refresh webservice - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: web-services, netbeans, jaxb, wsimport

When I try to import a webservice I get the following output:

```
ant -f /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient wsimport-client-clean-AdminService_1 wsimport-client-generate
wsimport-client-clean-AdminService_1:
Deleting directory /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient/build/generated/jax-wsCache/AdminService_1
init:
wsimport-init:
wsimport-client-AdminService_1:
Created dir: /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient/build/generated/jax-wsCache/AdminService_1
command line: wsimport -d /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient/build/generated/jax-wsCache/AdminService_1 -extension -Xnocompile -Xendorsed -keep -s /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient/build/generated/jax-wsCache/AdminService_1 -encoding UTF-8 -catalog /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient/catalog.xml -verbose /home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient/xml-resources/web-service-references/AdminService_1/wsdl/localhost_8084/WebFormsTest/AdminService.wsdl -p org.czentral.test.service -wsdllocation http://localhost:8084/WebFormsTest/AdminService?wsdl
parsing WSDL...


/home/bence/NetBeansProjects/WebClient/nbproject/jaxws-build.xml:22: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/Plugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1058)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findBaseClass(AntClassLoader.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1064)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at com.sun.istack.tools.MaskingClassLoader.loadClass(MaskingClassLoader.java:82)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:363)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.findServices(Options.java:952)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getAllPlugins(Options.java:374)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:81)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:265)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:347)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.<init>(ParserContext.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.<init>(XSOMParser.java:110)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:431)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:439)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2244)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:137)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:198)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:179)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2.execute(WsImport2.java:835)
    at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I looked around and everything seems OK:

- The project's *Libraries* include `JAXB 2.2.5 - jaxb-xjc.jar` which indeed contains the class in question.
- My jaxws-build.xml contains a classpath `${libs.jaxws21.classpath}`
- The value of `libs.jaxws21.classpath` defined in `~/.netbeans/8.0/build.properties` has a valid value, containing correct access to `jaxb-xjc.jar`

When I manually run the `wsimport` command displayed above it gives `unrecognized parameter -encoding` (an other version is run maybe in: /usr/bin/wsimport). With this parameter removed it works and generates the .java files. Manually moving them to `build/generated-sources/jax-ws` will let me compile the project.

I'm using Netbeans 8 (just installed) with Java 7 (openjdk-7-jdk) , I removed any previous versions (configurations moved to backup).

I'm pretty much out of ideas. Anyone else having the same problem? Are there any other settings I can check?

Comment: i have the same problem